# simple algorithm to find anagram

Tags: java, anagram

```
public class anagrm {
public static void main(String args[]){
    String s1 = new String();
    String s2 = new String();
    int count = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    s1 = sc.nextLine();``
    s2 = sc.nextLine();
    if(s1.length()==s2.length())
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < s1.length(); j++)
                if (s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(j)){
                    count++
                }

    if(count>=s1.length())
        System.out.println("string is anagram");
    else
        System.out.println("string is not anagram");
    System.out.println(count);
}


}
```

it is giving true for army and marr..i understood where the error is but i want to complete in this way...

Comment: Completely unclear. What is the error? what is the expected output? please explain more

Comment: @ibarrond he only wants it to return true if s1 and s2 are anagrams and currently it is sometimes returning true even if they are not (Because of repeat letters).

Comment: That might be true, but it is his task to state it clearly in the question. Otherwise it is useless for anyone else searching for it

Answer (score 1):

You run into errors as anytime a letter appears more than once in s1 you increment counter every time even if s2 only has that letter once. One way around this would be to use a `StringBuilder` instead and as you find a match in letters, delete that letter from s2 using the `deleteCharAt` method. To do this you would also need to change your second `for` loop to loop over `s2.length` instead as it would continuously be getting shorter. Not that elegant, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned your count variable is incrementing any time the letters match regardless of the number of times s1 has the letter. If you want to use a counting solution then you should increment the counts for each letter:

```
import java.util.HashMap
import java.util.Map

/* This is how to declare HashMap */
HashMap<char, String> s1map = new HashMap<char, String>();
HashMap<char, String> s2map = new HashMap<char, String>();

for (int j = 0; j < s1.length(); j++){
    //We create 2 hashmaps to count the number of each char in each word separately
    s1map.put(key, s1map.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);
    s2map.put(key, s2map.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);
}
```

Finally you can compare the resulting maps with:

```
if s1map.equals(s2map){
    print("They are anagrams")
}
else{
    print("They are not anagrams")
}
```